# img.height randomly returns 0 although i used load event

Tags: javascript, html

I posted that problem, but nobody answered, so I didn't explain it enough, I guess. So I will try it again.
I have the following html:

```
<div class="flexed row">
            <div class="column1 flexed column">

            </div>
            <div class="column2 flexed column">

            </div>
            <div class="column3 flexed column">

            </div>
            <div class="img-section">

            </div>
        </div>
```

And javascript:

```
const init = function () {

    let allGalleryData = [{
        galleryName: "Terénní seminář 2015",
        galleryThumbnailUrl: "gallery/Fotoseminar2015/",
        galleryFullSizeUrl: "gallery/Fotoseminar2015/big",
        galleryImages: [
            { url: '01.jpg', title: 'something', stars: 2.5, people: 91 },
            { url: '02.jpg', title: 'something', stars: 2.9, people: 42 },
            { url: '03.jpg', title: 'something', stars: 5, people: 19 },
            { url: '04.jpg', title: 'something', stars: 1.6, people: 31 },
            { url: '05.jpg', title: 'something', stars: 3.2, people: 20 },
            { url: '06.jpg', title: 'something', stars: 4.1, people: 43 },
            { url: '07.jpg', title: 'something', stars: 2.2, people: 21 },
            { url: '08.jpg', title: 'something', stars: 3.1, people: 82 },
            { url: '09.jpg', title: 'something', stars: 3.7, people: 18 },
            { url: '10.jpg', title: 'something', stars: 2.1, people: 58 },
            { url: '11.jpg', title: 'something', stars: 4.8, people: 98 },
            { url: '12.jpg', title: 'something', stars: 1.8, people: 25 },
            { url: '13.jpg', title: 'something', stars: 2.5, people: 41 },
            { url: '14.jpg', title: 'something', stars: 4.4, people: 33 },
            { url: '15.jpg', title: 'something', stars: 4.1, people: 28 },
            { url: '16.jpg', title: 'something', stars: 2.1, people: 53 },
            { url: '17.jpg', title: 'something', stars: 2.7, people: 24 },
            { url: '18.jpg', title: 'something', stars: 1.1, people: 72 },
            { url: '19.jpg', title: 'something', stars: 3.5, people: 96 },
            { url: '20.jpg', title: 'something', stars: 2.4, people: 3 },
            { url: '21.jpg', title: 'something', stars: 4.6, people: 32 },
            { url: '22.jpg', title: 'something', stars: 3.1, people: 45 },
            { url: '23.jpg', title: 'something', stars: 3.2, people: 23 },
            { url: '24.jpg', title: 'something', stars: 4.8, people: 19 },
            { url: '25.jpg', title: 'something', stars: 3.8, people: 13 },
            { url: '26.jpg', title: 'something', stars: 4.7, people: 71 },
            { url: '27.jpg', title: 'something', stars: 2.3, people: 96 },
            { url: '28.jpg', title: 'something', stars: 1.5, people: 84 },
            { url: '29.jpg', title: 'something', stars: 1.3, people: 13 }
        ]
    },
    {
        galleryName: "Skotsko 2014",
        galleryThumbnailUrlS: "gallery/Skotsko/",
        galleryFullSizeUrl: "gallery/Skotsko/big",
        galleryImagesNameUrl: [
            { url: 'Sk2014_01.JPG', title: 'Kanál v Amsterodamu', stars: 1.1, people: 24 },
            { url: 'Sk2014_02.JPG', title: 'Amsterodam (pobřeží)', stars: 3.4, people: 36 },
            { url: 'Sk2014_03.JPG', title: 'Trajekt do UK', stars: 1.3, people: 16 },
            { url: 'Sk2014_04.JPG', title: 'Pobřeží Skotska', stars: 3, people: 35 },
            { url: 'Sk2014_05.JPG', title: 'Urquhart Castle', stars: 2.3, people: 38 },
            { url: 'Sk2014_06.JPG', title: 'Břeh jezera', stars: 2.4, people: 50 },
            { url: 'Sk2014_07.JPG', title: 'Eilean Donan Castle', stars: 3.1, people: 31 },
            { url: 'Sk2014_08.JPG', title: 'Skotský skot', stars: 3.1, people: 40 },
            { url: 'Sk2014_09.JPG', title: 'The Old Man of Storr, Skye', stars: 2.9, people: 68 },
            { url: 'Sk2014_10.JPG', title: 'The Old Man of Storr, Skye', stars: 5, people: 71 },
            { url: 'Sk2014_11.JPG', title: 'Culloden', stars: 3.6, people: 45 },
            { url: 'Sk2014_12.JPG', title: 'Cawdor Castle', stars: 3.7, people: 31 },
            { url: 'Sk2014_13.JPG', title: 'Cairn Gorm', stars: 4.8, people: 77 },
            { url: 'Sk2014_14.JPG', title: 'Cairngorms National Park', stars: 4.8, people: 64 },
            { url: 'Sk2014_15.JPG', title: 'Tower Bridge', stars: 2.9, people: 61 },
            { url: 'Sk2014_16.JPG', title: 'Butler\'s Wharf', stars: 3.7, people: 78 },
            { url: 'Sk2014_17.JPG', title: 'London Eye', stars: 1.4, people: 85 },
            { url: 'Sk2014_18.JPG', title: 'Covent garden market - London', stars: 1.4, people: 76 },
            { url: 'Sk2014_19.JPG', title: 'Buckinghamský palác', stars: 2.4, people: 24 },
            { url: 'Sk2014_20.JPG', title: 'Big Ben London', stars: 4.2, people: 91 },
            { url: 'Sk2014_21.JPG', title: 'Big Ben London', stars: 3.5, people: 39 },
            { url: 'Sk2014_22.JPG', title: 'Big Ben London', stars: 3.7, people: 83 }
        ]
    }
    ]
    let column1Lenth = 0;
    let column2Lenth = 0;
    let column3Lenth = 0;
    let height;
    let source;
    let path;
    let image;
    for (const i of allGalleryData) {
        let seminar = i.galleryThumbnailUrl;
        let skotsko = i.galleryThumbnailUrlS;
        if (i.galleryImages) {
            for (const img of i.galleryImages) {
                path = seminar + img.url;
                let pic = document.createElement("img");
                pic.src = path;
                image = document.querySelector("img");
                image.addEventListener("load", function () {
                    height = pic.height;


                    //
                    console.log(height);//this should always return some number, but not a 0
                    //


                    if ((column1Lenth <= column2Lenth) && (column1Lenth <= column3Lenth)) {
                        column1Lenth += height;
                        source = document.getElementsByClassName("column1")[0];
                        source.appendChild(pic);
                    }
                    else if (((column2Lenth < column1Lenth) && (column2Lenth <= column3Lenth))) {
                        column2Lenth += height;
                        source = document.getElementsByClassName("column2")[0];
                        source.appendChild(pic);
                    }
                    else if ((column3Lenth < column1Lenth) && (column3Lenth < column2Lenth)) {
                        column3Lenth += height;
                        source = document.getElementsByClassName("column3")[0];
                        source.appendChild(pic);
                    }
                })
            }
        }
        else {
            for (const img of i.galleryImagesNameUrl) {
                path = skotsko + img.url;
                let pic = document.createElement("img");
                pic.src = path;
                image = document.querySelector("img");
                image.addEventListener("load", function () {
                    height = pic.height;


                    //
                    console.log(height);//this should always return some number, but not a 0
                    //


                    if ((column1Lenth <= column2Lenth) && (column1Lenth <= column3Lenth)) {
                        column1Lenth += height;
                        source = document.getElementsByClassName("column1")[0];
                        source.appendChild(pic);
                    }
                    else if (((column2Lenth < column1Lenth) && (column2Lenth <= column3Lenth))) {
                        column2Lenth += height;
                        source = document.getElementsByClassName("column2")[0];
                        source.appendChild(pic);
                    }
                    else if ((column3Lenth < column1Lenth) && (column3Lenth < column2Lenth)) {
                        column3Lenth += height;
                        source = document.getElementsByClassName("column3")[0];
                        source.appendChild(pic);
                    }
                })
            }
        }
    }
}
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", init);
```

I need to put the images from allGalleryData to the html according to some rules, which are related to height of the image. There goes the problem. I found out, that I need to use the load event, otherwise the img.height will be always 0. So I used the event, but in spite of this, the img.height is still 0 **sometimes**. Like every 10th refresh, the `console.log(height);` returns 0s. You can see it on the picture. So if somebody can help me, I will be very glad. I just need to have 100% chance, that `console.log(height);` returns right numbers.
Thank you very much
(I am sorry for my bad english)

Picture, that describes my problem: [image: weird values]

Picture, that shows right values: [image: right values]

Comment: Test with `console.log(image.height);` inside the `load` method once more.

Comment: @palaѕн I tried. That works, but `console.log(image.height);` always returns same number. So the image height doesn't change....

Comment: What’s with the use of `pic` and `image` there? Why are you working with two different variables there to begin with? Looks like that is probably the root of your problem. `image = document.querySelector("img")` will only ever get you the _first_ `img` element that exists in the document - so it doesn’t necessarily point to the same image as `pic` does.

Comment: _“That works, but `console.log(image.height);` always returns same number.”_ - because it is always the same image … This is not even connected to the _current_ `pic` element you are working with here, for `image` you are _always_ and repeatedly picking the first `img` element that actually exists within the DOM.

Comment: So you think that I should replace `image.addEventListener` with `pic.addEventListener`... or?